# Install nvm, node in closed network

Tags: node.js, nvm

I want to use multiple node version for my development.

Of course I know I can simply use nvm-windows *in normal case*...

But the problem is that
**the place where I want to install multiple node is company internal network**.

In closed network, if I use nvm install command like below... (I installed nvm by using exe file)

`$ nvm install v14.17.0`
`> Could not retrieve https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUM256.txt. Get "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUM256.txt": dial tcp 104.20.22.46:443: connctex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

It is not strange because network is closed.

I already tried msi/zip install, but I can install only one version of node...

### **My question is:**

How can I install multiple node versions in closed network?

Or anyone knows nvm install site list to firewall allow? (I can add to whitelist if I know url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can whitelist the nodejs website as by default nvm uses the official nodejs website to fetch the binaries (`https://nodejs.org/dist`).

You can check here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/c73009f50327b539f39c7e94504c8974b7d83c66/nvm.sh#L2029

In case you want to change the mirror for binaries you can find the guide here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#use-a-mirror-of-node-binaries

You will have to set the env as:
`export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist`